Could an insulator-covered copper plate be used as ground instead of grounding rod(s) buried in the ground?
Sometimes there are situations where I need to ground a device plugged into 220V/50hz AC but the plug is ungrounded. An example is using a generator that has a grounding rod but no place to stub it into the actual ground, or renting a cheap place but has poor electrical grounding and may take months in order to call an electrician (due to poor communication.)
Therefore, I thought up a solution for a somewhat no-dig-needed grounding in order to secure a single device.

The idea is to have an insulated copper plate reserving as a 0 voltage reference (afaik earth is a 0 voltage reference point thus upon an electrical fault current flows there.) The whole concept is to have a portable plug-n-play grounding where no digging or further modifications are required.
The device's earth will be connected into the electrode and the plate will act as grounding. Using leather or plastic handles I can carry it whenever I need to use it.
I feel like this is a stupid idea but I don't know why it is a stupid one. If it is a stupid how I could make a portable ground that requires no digging whatsoever?

The purpose of an earth ground is a compromise of various risks. The earth itself is not some absolute 0 V value. Such doesn't exist. And it is possible, with respect to a lamp stand for example, that earth (dirt) is at one million volts. And no, the idea you have doesn't hold water. The problem with ignorance is that anything can be considered possible, when sufficiently ignorant. The problem with knowledge is that most of what used to be possible no longer seems so anymore. And I don't mean any of this as disrespect. Just truth.

It depends what 'need'  in your first sentence means. If you need to ground a device for electrical safety, then you need uninsulated good conduction into the ground. If you need to ground a device 'because', then maybe you don't, and you can just do nothing. An insulated copper plate is either unnecessary, or insufficient.

The ground connection is supposed to connect to the same ground as the transformer outside your house uses.  The transformer ground is connected to the ground (the dirt) under your feet.  To make your house electrical circuits safe, the house ground must be connected to the ground (the dirt under your feet) as well.  A simple large conductor plate won't do you any good.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The ground rod in your house is supposed to connect the house ground wires to the transformer ground wire through the ground (the dirt.)  The red arrow illustrates the connection through the ground.
The point of all of this is to make sure that there's no point in your house where the voltage is higher than the outlet voltage and to make sure that the neutral wire is at the same voltage as the ground under your feet.  The live wire can still kill you, but the neutral and the ground are safe.  This is to reduce the chances of you killing yourself by touching one of the wires accidentally.
If you just connect a large copper plate to the house ground wire, you might as well not do anything.  You need that connection through the ground (dirt.)
You cannot make a "portable ground" that doesn't require digging.
A "portable ground" is about as realistic as the "portable hole" from the Road Runner cartoons.

